# Adding to an array in main via function argument

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm not sure if I even worded the title correctly, but basically. I want to know if there is a way to add to the buff array from the hey function using the pointers in the arguments and why does it work if it does?

buf[100].
example:

```
int main(){
  char buf[100];
  hey("320244",buf);
  printf("%s", buf);
}
  void hey(char* s, char* result){
  /*
  some code that appends to result using pointers
  do some stuff with s and get the result back in buf without using return.
  */
}
```

Comment: `buf` is uninitialized. How can you append to it? You could overwrite it.

Comment: You need to read a good C tutorial. Passing arrays to functions like this should be explained there.

Comment: I'm always open to suggestion! @Barmar

Comment: This is not valid C. Names must be declared before usage.

Comment: How about a good book? [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/445976)

Comment: [sample](http://ideone.com/7taSB4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly you mean the following

```
#include <string.h>

//...

void hey(char* s, char* result)
{
    strcpy( result, s );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void hey( const char* s, char* result);

int main(void) 
{
    char buf[100];

    hey( "320244", buf );

    printf( "%s\n", buf );

    return 0;
}

void hey( const char* s, char* result )
{
    strcpy( result, s );
}
```

Its output is

```
320244
```

If the array `buf` already stores a string then you can append to it a new string. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

char buf[100] = "ABC";

strcat( buf, "320244" );
```

Take into account that the function hey should be declared before its usage and according to the C Standard the function main shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: And this willl append back into the buf? Also lets say if you created a string within the scope of the function. How do you get it back to the main, would this work?

Comment: @Dnlfgby See my updated post. As for the second question then it is unclear. If you create a character array in the heap you can return a pointerto it from the function. On the other hand if you declare a local array then then you may not return a pointer to it.

Comment: Ahh, Okay. Thank you for clarifying this for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your code with some comments :-

```
#define LEN 100 //Use a macro instead of error prone digits in code

void hey(char* s, char* result); //Fwd declaration 

int main(){
  char buf[LEN] = {0}; //This will initialize the buffer on stack
  hey("320244",buf);
  printf("%s", buf);
  hey("abc", buf); //Possible future invocation
  printf("%s", buf);
}

void hey(char* s, char* result){
  if(strlen(result) + strlen(s) < LEN ) //This will check buffer overflow
    strcat(result, s); //This will concatenate s into result
  else
    //Do some error handling here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do the right thing, and use a structure to describe a dynamically allocated, grow-as-needed string:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct mystring {
    char   *ptr;  /* The actual string */
    size_t  len;  /* The length of the string */
    size_t  max;  /* Maximum number of chars allocated for */
};
#define MYSTRING_INIT { NULL, 0, 0 }
```

If we want to append something to a `struct mystring`, we define a function that takes a pointer to the structure the function can modify. (If it only needed a char pointer instead of a structure, it'd take a `char **`; a pointer to a char pointer.)

```
void mystring_append(struct mystring *ms, const char *s)
{
    const size_t slen = (s) ? strlen(s) : 0;

    /* Make sure ms points to a struct mystring; is not NULL */
    if (!ms) {
        fprintf(stderr, "mystring_append(): No struct mystring specified; ms == NULL!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Make sure we have enough memory allocated for the data */
    if (ms->len + slen >= ms->max) {
        const size_t  max = ms->len + slen + 1;
        char         *ptr;

        ptr = realloc(ms->ptr, max);
        if (!ptr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "mystring_append(): Out of memory!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ms->max = max;
        ms->ptr = ptr;
    }

    /* Append. */
    if (slen > 0) {
        memmove(ms->ptr + ms->len, s, slen);
        ms->len += slen;
    }

    /* We allocated one char extra for the
       string-terminating nul byte, '\0'. */
    ms->ptr[ms->len] = '\0';

    /* Done! */
}
```

The `(s) ? strlen(s) : 0;` expression uses the [`?:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) conditional operator. Essentially, if `s` is non-NULL, the expression evaluates to `strlen(s)`, otherwise it evaluates to `0`. You could use

```
size_t slen;

if (s != NULL)
    slen = strlen(s);
else
    slen = 0;
```

instead; I just like the concise `const size_t  slen = (s) ? strlen(s) : 0` form better. (The `const` tells the compiler that the `slen` variable is not going to be modified. While it might help the compiler generate better code, it is mostly a hint to other programmers that `slen` will have this particular value all through this function, so they do not need to check if it might be modified somewhere. It helps code maintenance in the long term, so it is a very good habit to get into.)

Normally, functions return success or error. For ease of use, `mystring_append()` does not return anything. If there is an error, it prints an error message to standard output, and stops the program.

It is a good practice to create a function that releases any dynamic memory used by such a structure. For example,

```
void mystring_free(struct mystring *ms)
{
    if (ms) {
        free(ms->ptr);
        ms->ptr = NULL;
        ms->len  = 0;
        ms->max  = 0;
    }
}
```

Often, you see initialization functions as well, like

```
void mystring_init(struct mystring *ms)
{
    ms->ptr = NULL;
    ms->len = 0;
    ms->max = 0;
}
```

but I prefer initialization macros like `MYSTRING_INIT`, defined earlier.

You can use the above in a program like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct mystring  message = MYSTRING_INIT;

    mystring_append(&message, "Hello, ");
    mystring_append(&message, "world!");

    printf("message = '%s'.\n", message.ptr);

    mystring_free(&message);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Notes:

- When we declare a variable of the structure type (and not as a pointer to the structure, i.e. no `*`), we use `.` between the variable name and the field name. In `main()`, we have `struct mystring  message;`, so we use `message.ptr` to refer to the char pointer in the `message` structure.
- When we declare a variable as a pointer to a structure type (as in the functions, with `*` before the variable name), we use `->` between the variable name and the field name. For example, in `mystring_append()` we have `struct mystring *ms`, so we use `ms->ptr` to refer to the char pointer in the structure pointed to by the `ms` variable.
- Dynamic memory management is not difficult. `realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)`, and `free(NULL)` is safe (does nothing).

  In the above function, we just need to keep track of both current length, and the number of chars allocated for the dynamic buffer pointed to by field `ptr`, and remember that a string needs that terminating nul byte, `'\0'`, which is not counted in its length.

  The above function reallocates only just enough memory for the additional string. In practice, extra memory is often allocated, so that the number of reallocations needed is kept to a minimum. (This is because memory allocation/reallocation functions are considered *expensive*, or slow, compared to other operations.) That is a topic for another occasion, though.
- If we want a function to be able to modify a variable (be that any type, even a structure) in the callers scope -- `struct mystring message;` in `main()` in the above example --, the function needs to take a pointer to variable of that type, and modify the value via the pointer.
- The address-of operator, `&`, takes the address of some variable. In particular, `&message` in the above example evaluates to a pointer to a `struct mystring`.

  If we write `struct mystring *ref = &message;`, with `struct mystring message;`, then `message` is a variable of `struct mystring` type, and `ref` is a pointer to `message`; `ref` being of `struct mystring *` type.